# git bash branches conflict

Tags: git, git-bash

I am new to git bash. I used to upload my projects on my github page online only using the website.

I need to use git bash in order to be able to upload bigger files. I uploaded successfully some files,
and I am not sure if I was supposed to "close" somehow the branch or delete it.

With my limited knowledge,
I reopened git in order to add some more files later, and used the command
`git init` yet again,
but now I can't push my files.

I think it created multiple branches. When I try to push, I get :

```
"Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g. git pull) before pushing again."
```

When I try git pull I have the following error :

```
"fatal: refusing to merge unrelated history",
```

or

```
git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

I get:

```
"Encountered 1 files that should have been pointers. but weren't. Automatic merge failed. Fix conflicts and then commit the result."
```

I think I also added a file that I did not commit in previously.
I figured this one file uses LFS (large file storage), because as I said I want to upload large files. By using `git lfs track "*.file-type"` it is tracking the file using a pointer.

When I retry here is the output

```
"your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged"
```

What am I missing ? what should I do?

Comment: Git and Bash are two different programs, with different purposes. There is a thing called "Git for Windows" that many people call "Git Bash" but it is nothing more than Git, Bash and several standard Un*x tools adapted and compiled for Windows and packed into a single package. Your issue has nothing to do with Bash. It's a Git issue but in its current shape your question is difficult to read and understand. Please format it nicely. Use an empty line to separate paragraphs, put `` ``` `` alone on a line before and after the Git commands you run or their output to format them properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! When it says that a file is not a pointer but should, it means that lfs tracking is enabled for this type of files, but this one file is not being tracked properly. Could be that lfs tracking for this type of files was enabled after adding this file, but the file wasn't commited. In this case you need to manually track it with  `git lfs track name-of-file.extension-of-file`. After this, if it doesn't let you merge, you need to add all files from both branches in conflict that are missing or were modified. `git add .`  adds the missing files for you, but you must have them in your directory too. Then `git commit -m "removed conflict"` and `git push`. That is all.